# WEXITSTATUS returning invalid exit status of popen() on success case

Tags: c, linux, bash, popen, pclose

I am trying to get the exist status of the child process using `popen()`.

**Case 1:** Calling function with the shell command returning error. This is working as expected.

```c
func("du -sh _invalid_file_");
```

**Output:**

```
du: cannot access '_invalid_file_': No such file or directory
Child exit value: 1
```

Here the child exist status is same as the exit value of `du` which ran in `bash`.

```
$ du -sh _invalid_file_
du: cannot access '_invalid_file_': No such file or directory
$ 
$ echo $?
 1
$
```

**Case 2: (Error case)** Calling function with the below shell command returning success.
In my code, `WEXITSTATUS()` returning `non-zero` value but the same command in `bash` returning `0`.

```c
func("du -sh");
```

**Output:**

```
Child exit value: 141
```

Please suggest to fix this issue. Pasted the code below.

```c
int func(char *cmd)
{
    FILE *pfp = NULL;
    int retval, status;

    pfp = popen(cmd, "r");
    if (pfp == NULL) {
        perror("popen failed");
        exit(1);
    }

    status = pclose(pfp);
    if (status < 0) {
        perror("pclose error");
    } else {
        if (WIFEXITED(status)) {
            retval = WEXITSTATUS(status);
            printf("Child exit value: %d\n", retval);
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I can't replicate your problem. If I do `func("du -sh");` then it exits with signal 13 (`SIGPIPE`) which you get from not emptying the pipe. If I read all output from the pipe then I get exit value `0` as expected.

Comment: I have reviewed the code and it is working for me. `Child exit value: 141`

Comment: How do you build? How do you run? What environment are you using to build and run? What distribution are you using? What version of the distribution?

Comment: I was running in Ubuntu 20. Compiled with GCC.
Here the complete source code. https://pastebin.com/raw/ZjyT4kD1

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You closed the pipe before actually reading any data from it. This would cause the child process to receive `SIGPIPE` (13) and be killed.

`popen()` would use `/bin/sh -c` to run the command so it's actually `sh -c "du ..."` running. When `du` was killed by `SIGPIPE` (13), `sh` would set the exit status to 128+13=141 and since `du` is the last command in the shell session so 141 would be the final exit status of the `sh -c ...` command and you got 141.

To fix it you need to read data from the pipe before `pclose()`.

```c
int func(char *cmd)
{
    FILE *pfp = NULL;
    char buf[1024];
    int retval, status;

    pfp = popen(cmd, "r");
    if (pfp == NULL) {
        perror("popen failed");
        exit(1);
    }

    /* read from the pipe or close() may cause the process to receive SIGPIPE */
    while (fgets(buf, sizeof buf, pfp) ) {
        printf("%s", buf);
    }

    status = pclose(pfp);
    if (status < 0) {
        perror("pclose error");
    } else {
        if (WIFEXITED(status)) {
            retval = WEXITSTATUS(status);
            printf("Child exit value: %d\n", retval);
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

---

The following is from `man 7 signal`:

```
   Signal     Value     Action   Comment
   ----------------------------------------------------------------------
   ... ...

   SIGPIPE      13       Term    Broken pipe: write to pipe with no
                                 readers; see pipe(7)
   ... ...
```

---

This `SIGPIPE` behavior happens every day though it is not obvious. You can try like this:

```
$ od /dev/urandom | head -n1
0000000 067255 052464 166240 113163 122024 054232 015444 110641
$ declare -p PIPESTATUS    # see PIPESTATUS in `man bash'
declare -a PIPESTATUS=([0]="141" [1]="0")
$
$ { od /dev/urandom; echo EXIT=$? >&2; } | head -n1
0000000 020553 063350 025451 116300 006505 151644 122151 175763
EXIT=141
```

---

Regarding the shell's `128+signal` behavior, the following is from `man bash` <sup>(Bash is sh-compatible so this also applies for sh.)</sup>:

> When a command terminates on a fatal signal  `N`, bash uses the value of `128+N` as the exit status.

Comment: Thanks @Pynexj. It is worked and marked as answer. In your comment, in exit status what is 128?

Comment: that's shell's feature. if a cmd is killed by a signal, the shell would set the exit status as 128+signal. you can try like this in an interactive bash: 1) `sleep 100`; 2) press ctrl-c to kill the sleep; 3) `echo $?` and you'll get 130 which is 128+2 and 2 is `SIGINT` (generated by ctrl-c).

Comment: note that SIGPIPE killing a process is only the DEFAULT behavior. a program can explicitly ignore it or do whatever it wants on receiving SIGPIPE.